# DoWhile in C# - OK - I need some help here bacause 

Tags: c#

... I admit, I only use DoWhile once in say 5 to 10 years, but when I need it, wow it's perfect, and now I have a great case for it on a personal project. Simple in c, c++ but have not tried it in c# until tonight. Yea I can get around it, but want to understand what is wrong with my environment/load/something better.

`[MSDN says][1]`:

"DoWhile Class

A looping activity that executes contained activities at least once, until a condition is no longer true.

Namespace:  System.Activities.Statements
Assembly:   System.Activities (in System.Activities.dll)"

I can't find the System.Activities.dll in the .Net references. I've unloaded all my previous vs loads so only have vs2010.

Anyone out there tried this? I'm probably missing something simple.

Thanks - Old Man

Answer (score 5):

Just use the do/while block:

```
int i = 0;
do
{
  i++;
} while (i < 10);
```

`System.Activities.DoWhile` is for Windows Workflow Foundation workflows.

Answer (score 3):

I assume you're trying to make a simple `do` loop.

[You need to use the `do` and `while` keywords](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/370s1zax.aspx), like this:

```
do {
    things;
} while(condition);
```

The [`DoWhile` *class*](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.activities.statements.dowhile.aspx) is a completely unrelated class that is used to make loops in Workflows.

Comment: Then you should accept this answer by clicking the hollow check.